# Undefined method errors after adding a library

Tags: android, undefined, showcaseview

I'm trying to use the [ShowcaseView](https://github.com/Espiandev/ShowcaseView) library, and for some reason after
making the reference to this library, I'm getting a following undefined method errors:

```
The method getActionView(MenuItem) is undefined for the type MenuItemCompat 
The method build() is undefined for the type NotificationCompat.Builder
```

in my project. Those classes are part of the `support-library-v4`. As soon as I remove the referencing to this project from the: `Properties->Library` window, the errors go away.

Now I have to say that there is another project in my workspace that uses this
library and working fine (The sample project of `ShowcaseView`), but my other project is not that lucky.

What could be the cause of that?

Comment: Looks like ShowcaseView also includes android-support-v4.jar, try to remove one of them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The comments were correct it was a jar mismatch, the reason why I didn't find it at first is because it wasn't a `support-library-v4` mismatch but one of the another jar files the `Showcase` library is using, after removing those two:

```
mockito-all-1.9.5
```

and:

```
robolectric-2.2-20130909.210745-40-jar-with-dependencies
```

the problem disappeared.

I have no idea what they are for, but the library works without them.

Comment: You save my day... Have the same problem and it drive me crazy! Thank YOUUU!